# Foreign key in Django Models does not seem to auto generate

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):

    jobname = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    freq_type = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    freq_interval = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    freq_recurrence = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    start_date=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    end_date=models.CharField(max_length=10, blank = True)
    start_time=models.CharField(max_length=6)
    end_time=models.CharField(max_length=6, blank = True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_modified=models.DateTimeField(null = True)
    version=models.IntegerField(default = 1)

class Job_detail(models.Model):
    job_type=models.IntegerField()
    json = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    jobid = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Job_track(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(default = 3)
    output = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank = True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 500, blank = True)
    jobid = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    jobdetailid = models.ForeignKey(Job_detail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
class JobForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = []

class JobDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job_detail
        fields = []
        exclude = ['jobid']

class JobTrackForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Job_track
        fields = []
        exclude = ['jobid', 'jobdetailid']
```

Within the function of my views:

```
def device_port_selected(request, pk):
    devices = Device.objects.get(pk=pk)        
    if request.method == "POST":
        job = JobForm(request.POST)
        jobdetail = JobDetailForm(request.POST)
        jobtrack = JobTrackForm(request.POST)
        if job.is_valid() and jobdetail.is_valid() and jobtrack.is_valid():
            #For Job
            j = job.save(commit=False)                  
            hostname = devices.id
            print(type(hostname))
            ipaddr = devices.ipaddr
            print(type(ipaddr))
            name = str(hostname) + ',' + ipaddr 
            j.jobname=name
            current_user = request.user
            j.owner = current_user.username
            j.enabled = "True"
            j.freq_type = 1
            j.freq_interval = 0
            j.freq_recurrence = 0
            servicedate = request.POST.get('servicedate','')
            print(servicedate)
            j.start_date = servicedate
            servicetime = request.POST.get('servicetime','')
            print(servicetime)
            j.start_time = servicetime
            j.version = 1
            j.save()
            
            #For Job_detail
            jobd = jobdetail.save(commit=False)
            selection=request.POST.get('portrange','')                      
            mode=request.POST.get('portmode','')                          
            status=request.POST.get('portstatus','')                        
            portpara1 = request.POST.get('portpara1','')               
            portpara2 = request.POST.get('portpara2','') 
            if selection == "":
                messages.warning(request, "Please select the ports that you want to configure")                                      
                return render(request, 'interface/device_port_selected.html',{'devices':devices, 'righttable':righttable, 'job':job} )    
            combined={"port_range":selection, "port_mode":mode, "port_status":status, "port_param1":portpara1, "port_param2": portpara2}
            combinedfinal = {"device":hostname, "ip":ipaddr, "configuration":combined}
            jobd.job_type=1
            jobd.json = combinedfinal
            jobd.save()         

            #For Job_track 
            jobt=jobtrack.save(commit=False)
            jobt.status=3
            jobt.save()
                                            
            return redirect('/device/', {'device':Device.objects.all, 'devices':device})
        else:
            print(job.errors)
            print(jobdetail.errors)
            print(jobtrack.errors)
            return render(request, 'interface/device_port_selected.html',{'devices':devices, 'righttable':righttable} )

    else:
        job = JobForm(request.POST)
        jobdetail = JobDetailForm(request.POST)
        jobtrack = JobTrackForm(request.POST)
        
    return render(request, 'interface/device_port_selected.html',{'devices':devices, 'righttable':righttable, 'job':job, 'jobdetail':jobdetail, 'jobtrack':jobtrack} )
```

When I try to press the submit button in my browser, I get the following error

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: interface_job_detail.jobid_id
```

Shouldn't a foreign key be generated by itself if I declare what table it is linked to? I linked the `jobid` of `Job_detail` table to `Job` table. But it does not seem to work. Can anyone explain how am I doing it wrong and show me a way to correct this?

Update:

I removed the `exclude` from my forms but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create and save a `Job` instance (named `j`) but there is no way the `Job_detail` instance (`jobd`) will automatically associate itself with that instance. You must specifically populate the foreign key before you save the instance, i.e.

```
jobd.jobid = j
jobd.save()
```

similarly for the `Job_track` instance (`jobt`):

```
jobt.jobid = j
jobt.jobdetailid = jobd
jobt.save()
```

As a side note have a look at [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and try to name your classes (e.g. `JobDetail` instead of `Job_detail`) and variables (`job_d` or better `job_detail` instead of `jobd`) in compliance with it. Your current naming scheme is confusing.

Comment: Regarding naming: the ForeignKeys should not have `id` in them either since Django will create a backing field `job_id` for a foreign key `job` anyway.

Comment: @AKX That's also true.

Answer (score -1):

because you use commit=False, is that not save the instance into db.

> This save() method accepts an optional commit keyword argument, which
> accepts either True or False. If you call save() with commit=False,
> then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the
> database. In this case, it’s up to you to call save() on the resulting
> model instance. This is useful if you want to do custom processing on
> the object before saving it, or if you want to use one of the
> specialized model saving options. commit is True by default.
>
> Another side effect of using commit=False is seen when your model has
> a many-to-many relation with another model. If your model has a
> many-to-many relation and you specify commit=False when you save a
> form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the
> many-to-many relation. This is because it isn’t possible to save
> many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the
> database.
>
> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using
> commit=False, Django adds a save_m2m() method to your ModelForm
> subclass. After you’ve manually saved the instance produced by the
> form, you can invoke save_m2m() to save the many-to-many form data.

you can see this from the documentation :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: This answer is incorrect. They explicitly save the `Job` instance after they add the extra information using `j.save()`. This is not an issue in this case.

Comment: oh ok, sorry i miss to read they not save the job instance